# selecting a field from pivot table using vba macro

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table using vba. I need help with the understanding of below-mentioned points.

1: I want to select(copy) values with certain filters (eg: Underlying price
for Instrument Type = OPTCUR, Symbol = GBPUSD). Basically a VBA alternative for formula

```
GETPIVOTDATA("Underlying_price",$C$4,"Instrument Type","OPTCUR","Symbol","GBPUSD")
```

2: I want to set "show detail=True" without knowing cell details but the criteria as mentioned above.

3: when we set "show detail=True" a new sheet opens. i want to asign this sheet to a variable of type worksheet.

below is the SS of my pivot table. and TableName:="My_Pivot"

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please shows us what you tried, what problems you encounter, and what is the expected output (a table, just one line, etc).

Comment: @LOKE2707 Did you check my answer? Does it work or not? How about any kind of comment below it to give a direction?

Comment: Extremely sorry for the late reply I couldn't reply sooner. @ASger your solution worked for all my questions. _myCell.ShowDetail_ was a little tricky, thank you for your example that really helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the relevant cell with [PivotTable.GetPivotData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.getpivotdata)
The new worksheet with details of this cell is shown by `Range.ShowDetail = True`.
Directly after that, the new `ActiveSheet` is the wanted one.

Here is a function to get the wanted worksheet with the details for a specified data field:

```
Private Function GetDetailSheet(pt As PivotTable, Val1 As String, Val2 As String) As Worksheet
    Dim myCell As Range
    With pt
        Set myCell = .GetPivotData(.DataFields(1).Name, _
            .RowFields(1).Name, Val1, _
            .RowFields(2).Name, Val2)
    End With
    myCell.ShowDetail = True
    Set GetDetailSheet = ActiveSheet
End Function
```

It can be used like this:

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = GetDetailSheet(ActiveSheet.PivotTables("My_Pivot"), "OPTCUR", "GBPUSD")
    ws.Name = "Details OPTCUR GBPUSD"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the (hideos) GETPIVOTDATA there's a solution for you!
It's called CUBEVALUE. It's a bit difficult to master but once it's done you reports & Pivot Table get to a whole new level.
See here: https://www.excelcampus.com/cubevalue-formulas/
Yes, it's a long article, but it's definitely worth the effort, as it would enable you to point to a specific *data point*, not to a specific *cell*.

Once mastered, adding a VBA code to a "changed" cell event and changing the visibility status of a certain sheet is just a matter of minutes.